# Managing python program settings through browser

Tags: python, xml

I am looking for a good way to manage the settings of a program I am writing. The program will be a service, so the user shouldn't have to interact with it at all. However, there will be a large number of settings to deal with (including a whole dirwalk), and I am looking for the best way to present that to the user.

Ideally, I would like something that would basically be a nice gui to an XML file I will build separately. I was thinking of doing it with Django, but I am trying to make the installation of this whole thing as simple as possible.

TL;DR: I dont know if it exists, but is there something that will cleanly present XML and allow for saving new settings to the XML document?

Comment: flask. install it write some js and away you go

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html